# Do I reference all my *.xml.gz sitemap files in robots.txt

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

I have a website with over 1 million url's. As such, I have 1 sitemap.xml file which acts as an index to many sitemap0000.xml.gz, sitemap0001.xml.gz ... sitemap0030.xml.gz etc. files.

My question is: In my robots.txt file how do I specify the sitemap file?

Do I refernce the sitemap.xml only? As in the following:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: www.mysite.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

Or do I have to specify ALL the *.xml.gz files in the sitemap too?

Comment: You *need* to include the protocol ("http://") when specifying the Sitemap URL in the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [only refer to the index file](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183669). (See under the "Using robots.txt" heading.) It will then lead the crawler to the others.